# .NET connecting to oracle problems with the connectionstring

Tags: .net, oracle, exception, connection

At the moment I'm trying to make a connection to a local server.
Connecting via, say, TOAD works fine. When I try to connect using .NET I get ora-12154.
Which puzzles me, since I'm using the connectionstring from my TNSNAMES.ora file:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myPC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

As follows:

```
private string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION ="
    +"    (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myPC)(PORT = 1521)))"
    +"    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE));"
    +"User Id=sys;Password=zsxyzabc;";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting as SYS.  Therefor you need to include the SYSDBA privilege:

```
+"User Id=sys;Password=zsxyzabc;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;";
```

It is bad practice to use the SYS account for regular application work, or even regular DBA work.  But it is necessary sometimes, and when it is necessary we have to connect `as sysdba`.

**edit**

It is a subtle one: you have a missing bracket at the end of the string!

```
private string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =" 
    +"    (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myPC)(PORT = 1521)))" 
    +"    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE)));" 
                                                                  ^
```

Having an IDE with bracket matching (I use TextPad) is a boon in these cases.

Comment: I tried logging in as a 'normal' user as well, with the same result.

Comment: Oh dear... VS doesn't show missing brackets in string, so I completely overlooked it.
Thank you for being sharp ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great site for sorting out your connection string issues:

[www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: The connectionstring is straight from the tnsnames file

Answer (score 0):

You may only be able to do this with the Oracle's .NET provider. That provider does support a "DBA Privilege=SYSDBA" setting in your connection string.

Why are you login with SYS user? It's dangerous, you may create a new user and connect with it. You may want to give any privileges you want. Try also this one :

```
string connString = "User Id=sys; Password=zsxyzabc; Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myPC)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SID=xe)))";
```